# solr hierarchical clustering

Tags: apache, solr, hierarchical-clustering, carrot2

I'm trying to enable hirearchical clustering (sub clusters generation) in Apache SOLR. For this I'm using the SOLR Clustering Component, setting the "outputSubclusters" parameter to true.

However, when I show the output in JSON, the object I receive from the clustering process  does not show any subclusters, which makes me wonder...what am I missing here?

Here is my clustering component in solrconfig.xml:

```html
 <searchComponent name="clustering"
                   enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                   class="solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent" >
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">lingo</str>

      <!-- Class name of a clustering algorithm compatible with the Carrot2 framework.

           Currently available open source algorithms are:
           * org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm
           * org.carrot2.clustering.stc.STCClusteringAlgorithm
           * org.carrot2.clustering.kmeans.BisectingKMeansClusteringAlgorithm

           See http://project.carrot2.org/algorithms.html for more information.

           A commercial algorithm Lingo3G (needs to be installed separately) is defined as:
           * com.carrotsearch.lingo3g.Lingo3GClusteringAlgorithm
        -->
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm</str>

      <!-- Override location of the clustering algorithm's resources 
           (attribute definitions and lexical resources).

           A directory from which to load algorithm-specific stop words,
           stop labels and attribute definition XMLs. 

           For an overview of Carrot2 lexical resources, see:
           http://download.carrot2.org/head/manual/#chapter.lexical-resources

           For an overview of Lingo3G lexical resources, see:
           http://download.carrotsearch.com/lingo3g/manual/#chapter.lexical-resources
       -->
      <str name="carrot.resourcesDir">clustering/carrot2</str>
    </lst>

    <!-- An example definition for the STC clustering algorithm. -->
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">stc</str>
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.stc.STCClusteringAlgorithm</str>
    </lst>

    <!-- An example definition for the bisecting kmeans clustering algorithm. -->
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">kmeans</str>
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.kmeans.BisectingKMeansClusteringAlgorithm</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

And the request handler:

```html
<requestHandler name="/clustering_en" startup="lazy" enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:true}" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <bool name="clustering">true</bool>
    <bool name="clustering.results">true</bool>
    <!-- Field name with the logical "title" of a each document (optional) -->
    <str name="carrot.title">id</str>
    <!-- Field name with the logical "URL" of a each document (optional) 
      <str name="carrot.url">id</str>-->
    <!-- Field name with the logical "content" of a each document (optional) -->
    <str name="carrot.snippet">answer_en</str>
    <!-- Apply highlighter to the title/ content and use this for clustering. -->
    <bool name="carrot.produceSummary">true</bool>
    <!-- the maximum number of labels per cluster -->
    <!--<int name="carrot.numDescriptions">5</int>-->
    <!-- produce sub clusters -->
    <bool name="carrot.outputSubClusters">true</bool>

    <!-- Configure the remaining request handler parameters. -->
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="qf">
      text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
    </str>
    <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    <str name="rows">100</str>
    <str name="fl">*,score</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="last-components">
    <str>clustering</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

I'm really clueless, and I thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source algorithm available in Carrot2 (which ships as part of Solr) can only generate flat clusterings. A [commercially available clustering algorithm](http://carrotsearch.com/lingo3g) can be plugged in to

Comment: Wow, thank you very much Mr. Osinski. It was very helpful. Our team will look at Lingo3G as you kindly suggested. Have a great day!.